# Dart Implementation for Patricia/Radix-Tree

Tags: dart, flutter, trie, radix-tree, patricia-trie

I am writing a flutter app. For this I have to cache some places and want to search for names. For this purpose, I would like to use a radix trie.
I have searched for implementations under dart, but I have not found anything useful.

Did anyone know where I can find an implementation? Or has anyone ever bothered?

Greetings Dagobert

Comment: I think it will be a few thousand. I just can not think of another elegant data structure. Do you happen to have a suggestion?

Comment: https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.3.0/dart-collection/dart-collection-library.html

Comment: I know that lib. But there are no trees inside. Or has it just another name?

Comment: `SplayTreeMap` maybe? the docs say: *"A Map of objects that can be ordered relative to each other.

The map is based on a self-balancing binary tree. It allows most operations in amortized logarithmic time."*

Comment: Hm .. SplayTreeMap is more a BST implementation, right? I need a tree with a suffix list or something similar.
I enter a key and want to get all the objects that contain this key.

Answer (score 1):

Radix-Trees are also called [Tries, Digital-Trees and Prefix-Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

You can find a Dart implementation of a Trie [here](https://pub.dev/packages/trie#-readme-tab-)